# Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed- Double

Tags: java

I am getting error for below code:
Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed

```
double triggerThresholdValue = triggerThreshold.doubleValue();
triggerThreshold = Double.min(triggerThresholdValue, 1) == 1 ?triggerThresholdValue/100 : triggerThreshold;
```

Comment: Will this work?double triggerThresholdValue = triggerThreshold.doubleValue();
            triggerThreshold = Double.min(triggerThresholdValue, 1) == 1 ? Double.valueOf(triggerThresholdValue/100) : triggerThreshold;

Comment: Is `triggerThreshold` a `Double`?

Comment: triggerThreshold = Double.min(triggerThreshold, 1) == 1 ? Double.valueOf(triggerThreshold/100) : triggerThreshold;...will this solve the issue?

Comment: Yes triggerThreshold  is Double

Comment: Please don’t add code in comments, it’s so hard to read. Better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51283864/edit) and add your code there.

Comment: @Sahil provide us with more codes from your project. It is hard to determine the correct answer on your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the code like this:

```
    if (triggerThresholdValue > 1.0) {
        triggerThreshold = triggerThresholdValue / 100.0;
    }
```

I believe it’s equivalent (have not done thorough testing). To me it’s easier to understand this way. There may be some corner cases with infinity, NaN and positive and negative zero, but if those values don’t occur in your code, you should be fine.

Why you got the message: Java needs to decide the type of the result of the ternary operator `? :`. Therefore the two possible result expressions (the one between `?` and `:` and the one after `:`) need to have the same type. In your code `triggerThresholdValue/100` has type `double` (small `d`, primitive), while `triggerThreshold` has type `Double` (capital `D`, object). I don’t know why Java chooses `double` over `Double`, but it has to make a choice. So in case the second value is chosen, the `Double` is first converted to `double`, that is, unboxed, and then converted to `Double` again, boxed, so it can be assigned to `triggerThreshold`. Where it also came from.

So yes, I believe that your suggestion in the comment will work:

```
    triggerThreshold = Double.min(triggerThreshold, 1) == 1 
            ? Double.valueOf(triggerThreshold / 100)
            : triggerThreshold;
```

This forces both expressions to have type `Double` (object) and thus removes the redundant unboxing and reboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this triggerThresholdValue.? We can directly use triggerThreshold

```
 triggerThreshold = Double.min(triggerThreshold, 1) == 1 ?Double.valueOf(triggerThreshold/100) : triggerThreshold;
```

*Edited: Used Double.valueOf for wrapping the value back